# Joining 2 subsets of same table with different conditions

Tags: hiveql, impala

| ID | Timestamp | type | account |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 212 | 2021-01-06 14:47:35 | 019 | ALA058748 |
| 212 | 2021-01-07 18:34:44 | 021 | API305575 |
| 212 | 2021-01-07 22:34:48 | 021 | XYZ565656 |
| 212 | 2021-01-08 00:31:25 | 021 | API305575 |
| 212 | 2021-01-08 00:31:31 | 021 | API305575 |
| 212 | 2021-01-08 00:34:44 | 020 | API305575 |
| 123 | 2021-05-21 03:34:44 | 021 | API305575 |
| 123 | 2021-05-21 05:34:44 | 019 | API305575 |
| 123 | 2021-05-21 09:34:44 | 021 | API305575 |
| 123 | 2021-05-21 03:34:44 | 020 | PQR464646 |

I have a table like above

I need to choose only those IDs for which -

Step 1)  MINIMUM(Timestamp) with type = 021 for an ID             --- Say X

Step 2)  (Timestamp) with type = 020 and with same ID and account as in X  --- Say Y

WHERE (Y-X) in minutes > 30

in this example - only ID 212 will be selected since for ID 123 , account with MIN(Timestamp) where type=021 <> account with type=020

Thank You

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: which dbms you are using?

Comment: Hive/Impala SQL

Answer (score 1):

Schema:

```
 create table t 
 (
     ID int, 
     Timestamp datetime,
     type int, 
     account varchar(50)
 );

 insert into t values(212, '2021-01-06 14:47:35', 019, 'ALA058748');
 insert into t values(212, '2021-01-07 18:34:44', 021, 'API305575');
 insert into t values(212, '2021-01-07 22:34:48', 021, 'XYZ565656');
 insert into t values(212, '2021-01-08 00:31:25', 021, 'API305575');
 insert into t values(212, '2021-01-08 00:31:31', 021, 'API305575');
 insert into t values(212, '2021-01-08 00:34:44', 020, 'API305575');
 insert into t values(123, '2021-05-21 03:34:44', 021, 'API305575');
 insert into t values(123, '2021-05-21 05:34:44', 019, 'API305575');
 insert into t values(123, '2021-05-21 09:34:44', 021, 'API305575');
 insert into t values(123, '2021-05-21 03:34:44', 020, 'PQR464646');
```

Query #1 for MySQL:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, min(case when type = '021' then timestamp end),
        min(case when type = '020' then timestamp end))>30
```

Query #2 for SQL Server:

```
 select id
 from t
 group by id
 having datediff(minute, min(case when type = '021' then timestamp end),
         min(case when type = '020' then timestamp end))>30
```

Output:

| id |
| --- |
| 212 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fe4025e01f7a1d5d983136afdde14f7d)*

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want using aggregation and filtering.  Date functions are notoriously database dependent, so the "30 minutes" logic probably differs on your database:

```
select id, account
from t
group by id, account
having min(timestamp) = min(case when type = '021' then timestamp end) and
       min(timestamp) < min(case when type = '020' then timestamp end) + interval '30 minute'
```

Comment: i need to consider the account as well , should be same for both timestamps for which time diff needs to be validated.

Comment: @AjinkyaPujari . . . If you need this for both the id/account combo, then just use that for the `group by`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you help me to get just the 2 timestamps values ? , i can figure out the difference logic. I thought of joining the table with itself , one instance with min(timestamp) where type = 021 and another instance with timestamp where type=020 , join based on ID and Account